# A Different Kind of Teapot Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

As the title says this is going to be a riddle similar to a teapot but a bit different. As with the teapot riddles I have a word that has 2 or more meanings. The twist is you are going to be given two different, but related teapots and have to decipher the teapot of theirs that are related. Sorry if there is any confusion I think it will make more sense once you look at the riddle. I will do my best to answer any questions and as always good luck!

---

> The first word's first teapot is an act of respect.
>
> The second word's first teapot is a tremble of fear.
>
> ***What is each word's teapot that relate to one another?***

More teapots for each word will be added if needed.

Comment: is this line 'The twist is you are going to be given two different, but related teapots and have to decipher the teapot of theirs that are related' the actual riddle?

Comment: To clarify, as an example, could one clue lead to a bow tie, and the other clue lead to the action 'to leave'. Their teapots could then be bough (of a tree) and leave(s) (of a tree). The connection then being a tree? **EDIT** wow I was actually really close with my example xD

Comment: Yeah sorry @Naemm Shaikh I couldn't find the right words to describe it well but AHKieran's example is exactly what I was trying to say. Hopefully that helps explain it for anyone still confused.

Comment: @gabbo1092 I got inspired and made my own one of these :D

Comment: Why are these called "teapot" riddles? It seems you've just replaced the word "meaning" or "definition" with "teapot". Is there some kind of meta-puzzle I'm missing that connects a meaning of the word "teapot" to a meaning of the word "definition"? If not, it only really obfuscates the puzzle.

Comment: @NuclearWang The naming of these riddle as teapot riddles is reference to a game as described on wikipedia  "The 'Teapot Game' is a word game described by Mary White's Book of Games, and involves guessing a word which is replaced by "teapot" in various sentences". It has been a bit of a popular riddle trend recently and calling them Teapot riddles is an easy way to differentiate them from others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The act of respect is

> Bow

And another word for tremble is

> Quiver

These are related because

> A quiver holds arrows, which are shot with the bow.

Comment: wow.. now I understood the puzzles