# Different Teapot Riddle - fanmade

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, knowledge

As inspired by @gabbo1092 in the [first of this kind of riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73155/a-different-kind-of-teapot-riddle) (see this for an example of how the answer works), I thought I'd come up with another riddle.

Rules:

- I will give you a number of clues.
- Each clue relates to a word.
- Each of these words will have a teapot (homophone/homonym) that
  has a different meaning.
- All of these teapots will be related in some way.
- Your task is to find each of the words, their teapots, and their connection.

> The first word has a teapot that means you feel sad and depressed.
>
> The second word has a teapot that is sweet and another teapot that belongs to William.
>
> The third word has a teapot that helps you fall asleep and feel calm.
>
> The fourth word has a teapot that both Indiana Jones and Ernest Shackleton would like versions of.

**HINT ONE**

> The third clue refers to a plant's smell.

**HINT TWO**

> The fourth clue refers to something edible.

**HINT THREE**

> The William in the second clue is dutch.

**HINT FOUR**

> The fourth word has potential prefixes. One of these prefixes is something to do with Indiana Jones, and a different prefix is something to do with Ernest Shackleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that they are all

> Colours

The first word has a teapot that means you feel sad and depressed.

> **Blue** - melancholy, sad, or depressed mood

The second word has a teapot that is sweet and another teapot that belongs to William.

> **Orange** - which is a sweet fruit but also a [feudal principality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Orange) of which [William III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_III_of_England) was prince.

The third word has a teapot that helps you fall asleep and feel calm.

> **Lavender** - already solved by Naeem Shaikh

The fourth word has a teapot that both Indiana Jones and Ernest Shackleton would like versions of.

> **Cream** - as in *whipped cream* (Indiana Jones had a signature whip) and *ice cream* (Ernest Shackleton was a polar explorer). Thank you to OP for the 4th hint.

Comment: You are extremely close! rot13(Gur svefg guerr nafjref ner pbeerpg, naq lbh ner evtug va gung gurl ner nyy pbybhef. Ohg V'z nsenvq gur sbhegu pbybhe vf abg pbeerpg naq gur gurzr npghnyyl fgnlf ng fvzcyl pbybhef naq qbrfa'g fgergpu nf sne nf GZAG :C Vs lbh pna svaq gur pbeerpg nafjre sbe gur sbhegu jbeq, V'yy znex lbh pbeerpg.)  I will add another hint for you :)

Comment: @AHKieran Okay, I've had an idea for the last one. Edited now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Perfect! Well done :D

Answer (score 6):

*I'm not going to pretend I fully understand these teapot riddles yet. So apologies if this is entirely the wrong approach.*

The teapots are:

> **Violet** is a shade of blue which is related to feeling sad or depressed
>  **Sweet Williams** are a flower that smells sweet and belongs to (named after) Prince William
>  **Lavender** smells are associated with relaxation and sleep. (Thanks to Naeem Shaikh)
>  **Bleeding Hearts** were suffered by both Ernest Shakleton (on a ship near Georgia) and Indiana Jones (in a temple near Doom)

All of these:

> Are names of purple flowers.

Comment: This was a great answer! As for the teapot riddles themselves; the answers are typically homonyms. Usually each hint is a different definition or representation of the word such as a synonym. +1 From me!

Comment: Good try! But you're getting the wrong end of the stick. Will add another hint :)

Comment: $(+1)$ This is just as good as the accepted answer, in my opinion. You will be getting a $50$ rep bounty! :D

Comment: No problem! It is just that many answers do not earn the credit they deserve, either for not being answered first or not being accepted. I am setting out bounties to give such credit, although it is based on my opinion (but I try to be kind) :P

Answer (score 3):

I think :

> Teapot - Love

Explanation:

> **The second word has a teapot that is sweet and belongs to William.** - A Lover's Complaint, love poems, love quote by william shakespeare
> **The third word has a teapot that helps you fall asleep and feel calm.** - Lavender. - Plant that makes you relax, sleep.
>  Both these contain Love(pronounciation)

so far I can only relate to these two.

Comment: The first word could be something about a ROT13(ebxra-urneg)

Comment: Nice try but your answer and first point are way off. However, your second point has found the right teapot, now to just find the others :)

Answer (score 2):

Could the answer be

> Pine

The first word has a teapot that means you feel sad and depressed.

> Pining away

The second word has a teapot that is sweet and belongs to William.

> Pine for love

The third word has a teapot that helps you fall asleep and feel calm.

> The scent of pine reduces stress or so

The fourth word has a teapot that both Indiana Jones and Ernest Shackleton would like versions of.

> Pineapple? Not sure of this

Comment: I'm afraid not, good try! +1