# Teaset - A Teapot Riddle Variation

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

To solve this type of riddle you must find 2 or more words that are homonyms or homophones that have a different meaning, A.K.A. teapots, that belong to a related set or group. If you have any confusion it tends to make more sense after seeing an example so [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73155/a-different-kind-of-teapot-riddle) is a past one done by me and [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73157/different-teapot-riddle-fanmade) is one done by @AHKieran.

Good Luck!

My third word seemed to be giving people some difficulty so I added a couple words that should narrow people's thoughts more. Next time I'll make sure my clues don't lead to as many possible answers.

---

> My first word's first teapot is number one
>
> My second word's first teapot you'll find with a pirate on the run
>
> My third word's first teapot famous fourth encloses the scene
>
> My first word's second teapot is small and green
>
> My second word's second teapot is a game with a mate
>
> My third word's second teapot structurally is first-rate
>
> ***What are all the words and how do they relate?***

**Hint for the set:**

> The words one, two and three, 
>  All are a type of me. 
>  But I am a teapot too you'll see. 
>  My first is something insane. 
>  My second often spread on something plain.
>  My third, the worst can be quite sensitive to pain 
>  
>  *P.S. You don't have to identify/explain the teapots of the set. The set just happened to also have multiple meanings and this seemed like a good way to help guide people to the solution.*

---

Added some more clues but had to change the order to make the rhyming work better in my head. Sorry if that causes any confusion.

Comment: That was a very good last hint you just added. Definitely seems like we got it then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and Second answers from @Emma

First:

> **Pee/Pea** - Number 1 / Small and Green

Second:

> **Chest/Chess** - Pirate on the Run / Game with a Mate

Third:

> **Wall/Wall** - as in the fourth wall for a movie/show scene / A solid structure

They relate in **(from @AHKieran)**

> Each teapot is the prefix for a type of nut. Peanut, Chestnut, Walnut!

Comment: Sadly this answer is incorrect. I really didn't think the third word would cause as much difficulty as it has so I may add a hint later if people are still struggling with that one. I will say the relation of the three teapots doesn't have anything to do with spelling or letters if that helps.

Comment: Changed the third answer... still completely unsure haha.

Comment: Your third answer is correct actually so congrats on being the first to find it. Now you just need to figure out the relation...

Comment: I HAVE THE CONNECTION!!!!  rot13(Gurl'er nyy cersvkrf bs AHG, JNYAHG, PURFGAHG, CRNAHG)

Comment: That has to be it... that's perfect! Nice!

Comment: I think you should edit it into your answer (ideally with credit to me ;) ) and then it might be marked correct

Comment: Done, and done.  Can't take credit for that one - the relationship was driving me mad and I was way off! Now we just need to see if it's right :)

Comment: I'm so glad you guys got it! It was also really cool to see all the teamwork for this question. Would you like the bounty now or later?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference to me. To be honest, I'm not even sure how bounties here work, haha... can you split the bounty?

Comment: Sadly no you can't split bounties. Some people will award multiple bounties to spread the reward to people who helped. If you are interested in learning more about bounties its all described here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 3):

My guess is

First word(s):

> Pee/Pea. Because of what #2 is... And a pea is small and green

Second word(s):

> Chest/Chess. A treasure chest. Chess the game.

Third word(s):

> Hold. With hold being to encompass. And the second being a ship's hold.

How they relate:

> They're all something that a person can do/have? I'm not really sure.

Comment: You are correct with the first two, the third and how they relate are incorrect though. Keep at it!

Answer (score 3):

From @Emma

First:

> Pee/Pea

Second:

> Chest/Chess

Now for the third:

> an **Act** might be related to closing a scene (drama/movie)
>  an **Ace** can be another word for first-rate (best at something)

They relate in:

> They are all "homophones" apart from the last letter

And,

> When combining the last letters from all 6 teapots, we get e,t,t,a,s,e which can spell **TEASET**

Comment: Sadly the third and relation for these is not what I had in mind but I love the creativity!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is

First:

> From @Emma - **Number one:** *Pee*; **Small and green:** *Pea*

Second:

> From @Emma - **Pirate on the run:** *Chest*, stealing treasure; **Game with a mate:** *Chess*, you can check-mate

Third:
Frame/Frame

> **Encloses the scene:** *Frame*, as in picture, camera or video; **Structurally is first-rate:** *Frame*, as in construction, when you put together of pieces to give a structure support and shape;

Relation:

> Not a clue, but I do think that frame fits well. Maybe someone else can shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

> The second word I believe is Rum/Rummy. Pirates famously drink rum, and there is the card game rummy.

Comment: Not quite but you've got the right idea