# Another Manufactured Teaset Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

I had an idea for another teaset riddle so here we go.

For anyone who doesn't know how these works you must decipher two or more words that are homonyms/homophones that have a different meaning, A.K.A. teapots. These teapots can relate to a specific set or group. If you don't understand fully here are some links to past ones:

- [A Different Kind of Teapot Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73155/a-different-kind-of-teapot-riddle)
- [Different Teapot Riddle - fanmade](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73157/different-teapot-riddle-fanmade)
- [Teaset - A Teapot Riddle Variation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73172/teaset-a-teapot-riddle-variation)

---

Each line has a clue for a different word that has at least two meanings/teapots. Find all the teapots and what set they belong to.

Good Luck!

> Add a sprinkle of this to almost every dish 
>  Then look at the past of existence 
>  For the last two lets not go crazy 
>  Or shall we?
>
> ***What are the words and how do they relate to one another?***

Hint 1

> Word one sometimes hot, sometimes not, sometimes just the delivery 
>  As the second, I have many teapots, one a famous Mr. me 
>  For the third, the hint was wild, but everything will be o**k** 
>  Finally the fourth comes in different types, freezing or Italian way

Hint 2

> Since there is still some confusion, 
>  of this particular teapot fusion, 
>  here are some clues for finding three and four. 
>  The third you must peel back the distractions. 
>  While the fourth makes up a large fraction 
>  of a lighter meal at a restaurant or store.

Hint 3

> For the third word, common colours it has three, 
>  It starts at one and changes over time you'll see, 
>  First its sick, then its happy and finally its brown 
>  At its final colour you should probably throw it down. 
>  
>  For the fourth word, think of caesar and garden, 
>  Keep thinking about the first colour and you won't be far then. 
>  Now put it all together, solution one, two, three and four, 
>  This should be enough hints, hopefully there will be no more.

---

Hopefully the hints are specific enough without being too easy. More hints may be added if deemed necessary.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the last two lines refer to the same word, or different ones? (Aka are there 3 in total or 4)

Comment: There are 4 total words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cashbee got the hard ones

Add a sprinkle of this to almost every dish

> PEPPER (credit to @Cashbee)

Then look at the past of existence

> BEAN  (credit to @Cashbee)

lets not go crazy

> Bananas. As in going bananas or crazy

Or shall we

> Lettuce -> Let us (shall we?)

The relation between them is

> Can be prefixed with green (green bananas, green lettuce, green beans, green pepper) or green and food

Answer (score 2):

Add a sprinkle of this to almost every dish

> PEPPER
> PEPPER 'to pepper' can mean 'to sprinkle'! Nice wordplay :)

Then look at the past of existence, a famous Mr. me

> BEAN
> Mr. Bean. Been is also the past tense of to be (past of existence).

lets not go crazy, the hint was wild, but everything will be ok

> CHIVE
> Chive and jive. There is **wild** chive, and going crazy would refer to the jive dance.
> Apparently, a letter is key in the hint. I'd guess its W but I can't make anything out of that.

Finally the fourth comes in different types, freezing or Italian way

> SLICE
> since pizza is neither homophone nor homograph, I'll go with slice. There's many types of pizza like Italian style, and you can buy your pizza frozen.

The relation between them is

> food

Comment: Your thinking and reasoning are right but your exact answers aren't. Give it some more thought and I am sure you'll get those two and hopefully from there you will have an idea of what the correlation is to help figure out the last two.

Comment: See edit. I could really use a hint :)

Comment: You got the first word an I am working on a hint to add later today that will hopefully help you figure some more of it out.

Comment: Edited my answer. Thanks for the hint, but the third and fourth are still really hard.

Comment: Your answer for the second word is correct. Sorry if the homophone was misleading in a teapot riddle. I had seen them before and I said in my rules that they could be used but I can see how that could be tricky if they normally aren't meant to be used. Your idea as far as the relation is also right. Its not the exact word I was thinking, but I would totally accept that as the set (If you wanted to try to get the exact word, Rot13:Gurer jnf n fcrpvsvp jbeq hfrq va gur gvgyr gung znl uryc lbh). The third word's hint Rot13:V unq n fcrpvsvp yrggre va zvaq gb thvqr lbh gb gur jbeq. Good luck

Comment: Oh. My fault - i didn't read the rules as I thought they were always repeating themselves. Sadly, these additional hints are not helpful to me. I tried an edit nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Partial:
Working from previous answers and the hints:

> Pepper (from @Cashbee) - a spice and the action of sprinkling
>   Bean/Been (from @Cashbee) - A legume and existed in past
>   Okra - "ocra" is in the phrasing and oK is in the hint and you have to peel it
>   Entree?  Can mean main dish and also ability to be part of a group.
>   Or - dessert/desert?

Comment: Answers for word three and four aren't right, but you are paying attention to the right things for the third word.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can put this all together:

For #1:

> @Cashbee found that it was Pepper.

For #2:

> @Cashbee found that it was Bean.

For #3:

> The hint appears to refer to a LEAF (since it starts green, then turns yellow (yellow is the colour of happiness), then brown and drops off the tree).

For #4:

> Caesar and Garden hints at SALAD.

Finding the common thread between the words, is it

> GREEN? Because you have Green Peppers, Green Beans, Leaf Green (or Green Leaves), and Green Salad.

Comment: You have the right idea with the colours but you may want to take a look at some of the other hints for the third and fourth word