# Teaset number 5

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Previous Teaset [can be found here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73373/another-manufactured-teaset-riddle)

Rules:

> - I will give you a number of clues.
> - Each clue relates to a word.
> - Each of these words will have a teapot (homophone/homonym) that has a different meaning.
> - All of these teapots will be related in some way.
> - Your task is to find each of the words, their teapots, and their connection.

Riddle:

> My first word is where you are right now, and no I'm not spying on you.
>
> My second word is an action performed to help what feeds you too.
>
> My third word comes after eating a musical fruit and no it's not poo.
>
> My fourth word is shouted before people fall over, but hopefully not you.
>
> And my connection can be utilised by flexible people.

Comment: `and no I'm not spying on you` - That's what all the people spying on me say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first word is where you are right now, and no I'm not spying on you.

> Earth (Planet/Dirt)

My second word is an action performed to help what feeds you too.

> Water (Water as in the action/ Water as in H20)

My third word comes after eating a musical fruit and no it's not poo.

> Air (Passing Gas/Heir?)

My fourth word is shouted before people fall over, but hopefully not you.

> Fire? (Stop drop and roll) (Fire/ Fire as in shooting)

And my connection can be utilised by flexible people.

> Bender, as in Avatar, Earth, Water, Air, Fire

Comment: Well done! I was more thinking rot13(Jvaq vafgrnq bs nve, naq gur pbaarpgvba orvat Ryrzragf (juvpu pna or hgvyvfrq ol oraqref va Ningne)) But you're close enough :)

Comment: Ah yes, that is what I was thinking, but didn't phrase it very well